# how to Convert String To Float in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hello guy i am creating calculator and i want to convert these values to float
    string num = "2+6+8+9";
so they will automatically add and give total of 25?
is there anyway to do this?

sorry for my bad english

Comment: `float string`? you want to end up with `num = 25`, `25`? `25.0`?

Comment: You need to use jquery. Obviously.

Comment: @blowdart first the question is about c#, also to evaluate an expression a pure javascript is enough. Why jQuery?

Comment: Thanks for answers
I am a student and learning C#
I can't use java neither jQuery
but i found my answer thanks again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DataTable.Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) ;-)

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
int i = (int) table.Compute("2+6+8+9", null);  // 25
```

For all rules and which operators are supported: [`DataColumn.Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)

If you don't know the type of the result use a floating point type always and [`System.Convert.ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3x7f55.aspx) which accepts everything that's `IConvertible`, for example:

```
double d1 = System.Convert.ToDouble(table.Compute("2+6+8+9", null));   // 25.0
double d2 = System.Convert.ToDouble(table.Compute("2+6+8+9/2", null)); // 20.5
```

Comment: That's super cool - I totally didn't know that existed. I would have assumed one would need a third-party expression evaluator, or to write your own. Good to know!

Comment: That is cool nice addition to my toolbox.

Comment: One more question how to treat this expression
`"2+6+8+9/2"`

Comment: You just have to cast it to the correct type: `double d = (double)table.Compute("2+6+8+9/2",null);`. If you don't know the type of the result use a floating point type always and `System.Convert` which accepts an `object`, for example: `double d = System.Convert.ToDouble(table.Compute("2+6+8+9", null));`

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an expression evaluator. There are many available. For example: http://csharpeval.codeplex.com/

Comment: Is this an answer or comment?

Comment: @I4V It is an answer. Do you think it should be a comment?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think, 4 years experience on SO is enough to know link-only answers are not welcomed.

Comment: @L.B It's not a link only answer. It names the key search term, *expression evaluator*. If the asker knew of that term he'd have found hundreds of them before even asking the question. It's not the best answer in the world I agree.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And this makes it an answer? I would expect a code showing how it could be done.

Comment: @L.B I'm sorry to have disappointed you.

Answer (score 1):

The question asked in your subject is straight forward. You can convert a string to a float like this:

```
double f = double.Parse("2.5");
```

However, if you want to handle arbitrary expressions as described in your question, that requires a bit more work. Fortunately, others have done this work. I wrote my own expression evaluator and you can see it in my article [A C# Expression Evaluator](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/a-c-expression-evaluator). It supports variables and functions in addition to supporting the sample expression in your question.

Answer (score -1):

This may get you what you want:

```
    string[] inputArray = Regex.Split(num, @"\D+");
    float results = 0;

    foreach (var item in inputArray )
    {
        results += float.Parse(item);
    }
```

Comment: What if expression contained  operators other than `+`?

Comment: Does not matter each number will be split out in the array no matter what is separating them the + = positive.

Comment: No, @L.B is asking what happens when you feed in `"7*6"` for example

Comment: OK he ask how to add, not how to multiply :)

Comment: Thank for the down vote, but you know he may have just used + as a example of a separator in a string, and it could be anything like comma or a semicolon.

Comment: If we can make assumptions that all operators will be a `+` then we can also assume all numbers will be only a single digit (according to the sample in question). Then this could also work: `"2+6+8+9".Where(char.IsDigit).Sum(c => c - '0');` :)

Comment: @N4TKD 7*6 != 13 and what about operator precedence, what about 4+3*2?